# Find letter combination on phone keypad

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, combinations

I'm working on an app which is a dialer and I want to search contacts when user presses keys. I want to search contacts which match phone number as well as name of contact. I've implemented method to search contact based on phone number, when user presses key, it'll search the number similar to the keys pressed.

My code is:

```
List<string> a = new List<string>();
var alphabet = "abc";
var al2 = "def";

var q = alphabet.Select(x => x.ToString());
int size = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    q = q.SelectMany(x => al2, (x, y) => x + y);

foreach (var item in q)
    a.Add(item);

SearchListbox.ItemsSource = listobj
    .FindAll(x => x.Phone.Contains(str) || 
        x.FirstName.Contains(a.Any().ToString()));
```

It works perfectly for number search but not for name search.

I want to search contacts which match letter combinations when user presses keys. How do I do that? I'm building an app for windows phone so it must be in c#.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please edit your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: I still don't understand how the code you have shown "doesn't work". Can you elaborate?

Comment: I also don't know how your code (except maybe the last statement) has any relevance to your question.

Comment: @gunr2171 it works for number only, it doesnt search for contact name

Comment: You already said that. We need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a good job for regular expressions! here's an example i whipped up to use regex to search through:

```
        var names = new List<string>();
        names.Add("alice");
        names.Add("bob");
        names.Add("charlie");

        var digitMap = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            { 1, "" },
            { 2, "[abcABC]" },
            { 3, "[defDEF]" },
            { 4, "[ghiGHI]" },
            { 5, "[jklJKL]" },
            { 6, "[mnoMNO]" },
            { 7, "[pqrsPQRS]" },
            { 8, "[tuvTUV]" },
            { 9, "[qxyzQXYZ]" },
            { 0, "" },
        };

        var enteredDigits = "26";
        var charsAsInts = enteredDigits.ToCharArray().Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString()));

        var regexBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var val in charsAsInts)
            regexBuilder.Append(digitMap[val]);

        var pattern = regexBuilder.ToString();

        //append a ".*" to the end of the regex to make it "StartsWith", beginning for "EndsWith", or both for "Contains";
        pattern = ".*" + pattern + ".*";

        var matchingNames = names.Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, pattern));

        Console.WriteLine("Matching input: " + enteredDigits + " as regex: " + pattern);

        foreach (var n in matchingNames)
            Console.WriteLine(n);
```

In this example, I had "26" as the input, which filters out all but "bob". If you remove the 6 you'll find it returns all three, as they all have a, b, or c in their names.

FYI, if you wanted it to match the number as well, simply add the number to the regex string value in the dictionary.

Comment: its working fine but I think it doesnt search for all the matches.

Comment: what do you mean? provide an example

Comment: what if there is a Last name too? it will not work so check my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/75168930/5155422

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Windows Phone development but I know there is contact search functionality that is part of the Windows Phone SDK.

Have you tried looking into the Contacts class' SearchAsyc method?

It might not work for this type of search but it seems like a common type of search for phone contacts.

If that isn't possible I'd say DLeh's solution would work well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this C# code, which will store the data Trie data structure, and then perform a search on it.
The TrieNode represents a node in the Trie, which contains a dictionary of child nodes and a boolean that indicates if the node represents the end of a word or not

```
   class TrieNode
{
     public Dictionary<char, TrieNode> children = new Dictionary<char, TrieNode>();
     public bool isEndOfWord;
     public string contact;
}

class Trie
{
public TrieNode root = new TrieNode();

public void Insert(string contact)
{
    TrieNode current = root;
    foreach (char c in contact)
    {
        if (!current.children.ContainsKey(c))
        {
            current.children.Add(c, new TrieNode());
        }
        current = current.children[c];
    }
    current.isEndOfWord = true;
    current.contact = contact;
}

public List<string> Search(string prefix)
{
    TrieNode current = root;
    List<string> contacts = new List<string>();
    foreach (char c in prefix)
    {
        if (!current.children.ContainsKey(c))
        {
            return new List<string>();
        }
        current = current.children[c];
    }
    GetAllContacts(current, contacts);
    return contacts;
}

private void GetAllContacts(TrieNode node, List<string> contacts)
{
    if (node.isEndOfWord)
    {
        contacts.Add(node.contact);
    }
    foreach (var child in node.children)
    {
        GetAllContacts(child.Value, contacts);
    }
}
}

class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Add some contacts to the Trie
    Trie trie = new Trie();
    trie.Insert("John Smith");
    trie.Insert("Jane Smith");
    trie.Insert("Bob Johnson");
    trie.Insert("Mike Taylor");
    trie.Insert("Michael Jordan");

    // Search for contacts that match the prefix "Mi"
    List<string> contacts = trie.Search("Mi");
    foreach (string contact in contacts)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(contact);
    }
}
}
```

As an alternative you may use an elastic search or Solr

Answer (score -1):

**I can Filter 1500+ Contact in only 0.5 second**

**You can create same as List< String> or you can go with Object like List< Contact> and just change condition.**

**FYI :Code in java but you need to check logic**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> contactList= new ArrayList<String>();
        contactList.add("Jason  Arnold 9875454454");
        contactList.add("Joshua Ferguson 789455482121");
        contactList.add("Sarah  Churchill 78452165982");
        contactList.add("Brandon    Walsh 78452121");
        contactList.add("Justin Cameron 452197821");
        contactList.add("Rebecca    Howard 784521983232");
        contactList.add("Trevor Smith 372753221");
        contactList.add("Heather    Fraser 9884562145");
        contactList.add("Caroline   Peters 6598421");
        contactList.add("Chloe  Lyman");


        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hm.put("2", "[2abc]");
        hm.put("3", "[3def]");
        hm.put("4", "[4ghi]");
        hm.put("5", "[5jkl]");
        hm.put("6", "[6mno]");
        hm.put("7", "[7pqrs]");
        hm.put("8", "[8tuv]");
        hm.put("9", "[9wxyz]");
        hm.put("1", "[1]");
        hm.put("0", "[0]");

        Instant startTime = Instant.now();
        String findContact = "3727"; // todo
        String regEx = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < findContact.length(); i++) {
            regEx = regEx + hm.get(findContact.charAt(i) + "");
        }

        String finalRegEx = "^"+regEx+".*$";
        System.out.println("!_!_" + finalRegEx);

        List<String> ll = contactList.stream().filter(s -> isMatched(s, finalRegEx))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
                
        for (int i = 0; i < ll.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("-->: " + ll.get(i));
        }

        Instant current = Instant.now();
        System.out.println("\nFound List size: " + ll.size());
        long milliseconds = (current.toEpochMilli() - startTime.toEpochMilli());
        System.out.println("\nmilliseconds: " + milliseconds);
    }

    private static boolean isMatched(String str, String finalRegEx) {
        String[] arrOfStr = str.split("\\s");
        for (String a : arrOfStr) {
            if (a.toUpperCase().matches(finalRegEx.toUpperCase()))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Result :**

Trevor Smith 372753221 **(as Phonenumber start with 3727)**

Heather Fraser 9884562145 **(as Last name match with 3727 dial pad keys)**